# Citadel mail server - Need MAIL before RCPT

Tags: email, mail-server

Using Citadel mail server in a private VM.

Whenever I try to send a message from a mail client (thunderbird, outlook, etc) I get the error from the mail server:

`Need MAIL before RCPT.`

I'm using port 587 to connect to the mail server.

If I send the email through webcit it works. Receiving emails with the mail clients also work without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set `Primary Internet e-mail address` in the `Edit user account` interface:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBsjS.png)